# Is there a way to subclass and override a method that is in a custom namespace?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, flex4

Say I have a class with a method defined in a namespace other than public, protected or internal...

```
package com.foo.bar
{
   import com.foo.my_name_space
   public class bar
   {
    private var _vabc:String
    private var _v123:String

    protected function set123(val:String):void{
        _v123 = val;
    }

    my_name_space function setABC(val:String):void{
        _vabc = val;
    }

   }
}
```

Now I want to extend and override this in a subclass...

```
package com.foo
{
   import com.foo.bar.bar
   import com.foo.my_name_space

   public class foo extends bar
   {
      override protected function set123(val:String):void{
        super.set123(val);
      }

       .... ????? ...

   }
 }
```

Easy enough to override protected, public etc. methods, but is there a way to override the setABC method defined in the name space *my_name_space* ?

I've tried the following syntax, which seems to pass the FlashBuilder pre-compiler check but doesn't work.

```
    use namespace my_name_space override function my_name_space::setABC(val:String):void
```

I've tried a number of other syntax combinations but most wouldn't even pass the pre-compile check. (many with some type of namespace error)  I have a feeling this isn't possible but wonder if anyone might have any ideas?

Comment: How are you declaring your namespace? Can we see the code for that please? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

James' answer is right. You just failed to add the `use namespace` directive appropriately. This example works as expected:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import test.Base;
    import test.Child;
    import test.my_namespace;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        use namespace my_namespace;

        public function Main():void {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var base:Base = new Base();
            base.test();

            var child:Child = new Child();
            child.test();
        }

    }

}

package test {
    import test.my_namespace;
    use namespace my_namespace;

    public class Base {

        my_namespace function test():void {
            trace("Base");
        }

    }

}

package test {
    import test.Base;
    import test.my_namespace;
    use namespace my_namespace;

    public class Child extends Base {

        public function Child() {

        }

        override my_namespace function test():void {
            trace("Child");
            super.my_namespace::test();
        }
    }

}

package test {
    public namespace my_namespece;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I thought this too, posted it as a comment. Thanks for providing the full implementation.

Comment: Also with all that said I'd like to caution (politely) Justin about being so bitter with people trying to help you and also about marking peoples answers down. We're all here to learn.

Comment: I apologize to @james-lyon and have removed my comment I am often not the most warm and fuzzy person.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
override my_name_space function setABC(val:String):void
{   
}
```

Comment: He might actually be right. From what research I've done, this is the proper way to override a method from a custom namespace. Ensure you are calling "using namepspace my_namespace" somewhere before this override in your class. If this isn't working for you, then you've probably defined your namespace as a private namespace.

Comment: sorry can't mark this as the answer as it was incomplete.  This syntax will work... provided you also use the the "use namespace" directive.