# Override function in a namespace WITHOUT opening the namespace for the entire class

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces, overriding, access-modifiers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422544/is-there-a-way-to-subclass-and-override-a-method-that-is-in-a-custom-namespace) is similar, but that solution doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

So I've got a namespace:

```
package src {
    public namespace dangerous;
}
```

A class with a function in that namespace:

```
package src {
    public class Parent {
        dangerous function doDangerousThing():void {
            //something dangerous
        }

        dangerous function doReallyDangerousThing():void {
            //something really dangerous
        }
    }
}
```

And a class that needs to override a function in the namespace:

```
package src {
    public class Child extends Parent {
        override dangerous function doDangerousThing():void {
            //some different dangerous thing
        }

        public function doInnocuousThing():void {
            //sneakily attempt to access super.doReallyDangerousThing
            //(or something dangerous in another class)
        }
    }
}
```

I can add `use namespace dangerous` above the class definition of `Child` as suggested in the answer linked above, but the reason I'm using a namespace is to restrict access to potentially dangerous functions. Is there anyway I can open the namespace *only* so I can put the overriding function in it?

I was certain there wasn't a solution, but I'd feel silly if I come up with a complicated workaround only to find out this is possible 6 months from now.